# Select top n filtered rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets I have a table like this:

```
JOB             TYPE       STATUS
Generate files  Scheduled  In Progress
Update certs    Manual     Completed
Copy files      Scheduled  Pending
... (hundreds of rows)
```

Rows are sorted by descending priority. I need to count the STATUS values of the top 20 “Scheduled” jobs:

```
Top 20 Scheduled Jobs: Completed:   2
                       In Progress: 4
                       Pending:     14
```

I can use FILTER to select all the “Scheduled” jobs, but how do I select the “top 20” rows from that result (meaning the first 20 rows after the filter has been applied)?

Comment: From the table you gave, I'm not able to prioritize the scheduled jobs. How do you select the top 20 rows?

Comment: I simplified things for this example, where the rows themselves are already sorted by descending priority. The prioritization itself wasn't the issue here -- it was how to select the first 'n' rows out of the filtered results. ARRAY_CONSTRAIN() was the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UNTESTED. Please try:

```
=countif(array_constrain(filter(C:C,B:B="Scheduled"),20,1),E2)
```

and cop down where E2, E3 and E4 contain `Completed`, `In Progress` and `Pending` respectively.

Comment: ARRAY_CONSTRAIN() was the solution I needed, and your code showed how to use that result set. Thanks.